# Codeigniter : Pass data from view to controller using anchor tag

Tags: php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I am working on a project where I need to pass an ID to controller when someone clicks on the link, and open response in new tab.

I googled for solution on this, but couldn't find proper result. I also tried by sending data through URL in anchor tag, but then it gave an error of config.php file, so I reversed the code.

Currently I am using form tag to pass data. Can ye do this using PHP, or will we have to take help of jquery?

Here's View code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action='<?php echo base_url() . "home/edit_policy"; ?>'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="polid" name="polid" value="<?php echo $ajax_view_pol_response[0]->polid; ?>">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="editpolsubmit">Edit this Policy</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</font>
```

This code is from Controller:

```
   public function edit_policy() {
        $polid = $this->input->post('polid');
}
```

I want to transfer the "polid" from view to controller function using anchor tag.

All positive suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what means: *but then it gave an error of config.php file, so I reversed the code*?

Comment: also this is a good read: [URI Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html?highlight=segment#CI_URI) and [Url Helper - anchor](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have added the code to this question.

Comment: I don't see any link yet.